# Custom datatype or HashMap for relationship between nodes in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Is it possible to have value of a relationship between node as a user-defined class or it should be a primitive datatype. For example:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "ALIGNED_WITH")
public class AlignedWith {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private Set<DeptEndorsement> deptEndorsement = new HashSet<>();

    @StartNode
    private Term startTerm;

    @EndNode
    private Term endTerm;

    // getters and setters

}


public class DeptEndorsement {

    private String deptName;
    private Integer endorsementCount;

    // getters and setters

}


@NodeEntity
public class Term {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String termName;

    @Relationship(type = "ALIGNED_WITH", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<AlignedWith> alignedWith = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAlignedWith(AlignedWith alignedWith) {
        this.alignedWith.add(alignedWith);
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

If you observe `DeptEndorsement` is a custom class which I want as value for relationship `AlignedWith`

Or, is it possible to have a `HashMap` (example: `HashMap<String, Integer>`) as the value for the relationship between nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my finding for this question, supported datatypes in Neo4J are:

Boolean, Long, Double, String, List. Types that can be type casted are Short, Integer, Float (though you need to specify that you allow casting, check below if condition) [Ref. MapCompositeConverter.java](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/typeconversion/MapCompositeConverter.java)

Below condition was responsible to check if the type is supported by Neo4J or not, through in my case I did not provide `allowCast` to be `true` and thus `java.lang.Integer` was not castable:

```
if (isCypherType(entryValue) || (allowCast && canCastType(entryValue)))

private boolean isCypherType(Object entryValue) {
    return cypherTypes.contains(entryValue.getClass()) || List.class.isAssignableFrom(entryValue.getClass());
}
```

I changed from `java.lang.Integer` to `java.lang.Long` and everything works fine. You can not use custom datatype as in my case `DeptEndorsement`

Below is how my properties look like for a relationship.

```
@Properties
private Map<String, Long> deptEndorsement = new HashMap<>();
```

`@Properties` annotation is available in `neo4j-ogm-core` 3.0.0+ [Ref: Compatibility](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-ogm/#_compatibility)